# Flutter - How to download-to-excel for mobile and web?

Tags: excel, flutter, dart, cross-platform

I have a download to excel functionality which works fine for web, but the code won't even compile for mobile.

```
          downloadExcelFile() async {
        // Convert the Excel data to bytes
        final excelBytes = excel.encode();

        if (kIsWeb == true) {
          // Serve the file as a download (web implementation)
          final blob = html.Blob([excelBytes],
              'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
          final url = html.Url.createObjectUrl(blob);

          final anchorElement = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
            ..setAttribute('download', 'Job_Data_Export.xlsx')
            ..click();

          // Clean up and release the object URL
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
          anchorElement.remove();
          html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
        } else {
          // Write the data to a file (mobile implementation)
          final file = File('Job_Data_Export.xlsx');
          await file.writeAsBytes(excelBytes!);

          // Share the file on mobile
          final filePath = file.path;
          await share.Share.file(
            'Job Data Export',
            'Job_Data_Export.xlsx',
            excelBytes,
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
            text: 'Check out the exported job data.',
          );
        }
      }
```

It throws:

```
: Error: Method not found: 'Blob'.
job_list_controller.dart:253
      final blob = html.Blob([excelBytes],

                        ^^^^
: Error: Undefined name 'Url'.
job_list_controller.dart:255
      final url = html.Url.createObjectUrl(blob);
                       ^^^
: Error: Method not found: 'AnchorElement'.
job_list_controller.dart:257
      final anchorElement = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
```